# How can I generate a random mp3 file?

Tags: audio, mp3

For a personal project I'm trying to write some code that will generate an MP3 file with random noise. I opened up an mp3 file in sublime text and saw that there was a hexadecimal format of thousands of lines of 8 sets of 4 hexidecimal numbers in the file. Ex...

> 4944 3303 0000 0002 0c27 5459 4552 0000
>
> 0005 0000 0032 3031 3454 5055 4200 0000
>
> 1f00 0001 fffe 4800 6500 6c00 6c00 6f00

So I wrote some code to randomly generate millions of lines of that. The issue is that when I try to open it in itunes or VLC it says the song is zero seconds long. This makes me think that there is some sort of metadata that the random generation is botching up. Is there a simple guide on how to make an mp3 file from scratch or a guide on how to make sensible metadata?

Comment: The file is a binary format. That pretty formatted hex dump is just how your text editor decided to show it to you. Your best bet is to stuff a random byte stream into an actual mp3 encoder.

Comment: Must your project use the MP3 format. You might be better off using a wav file as [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) supports it, and can read and write wav files. Also wav is an open standard unlike mp3, and you can find open encoders to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the [THE MP3 SPECIFICATION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mp3filestructure.svg) it will tell you which bits represent what, and *perhaps* some bits need to be hardcoded to specific values?